# What differences are between the different ways of specifying `datapart` arguments?

Tags: sql, sql-server

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql

The following table lists all `datepart` arguments with corresponding return values for the statement `SELECT DATEPART(datepart,'2007-10-30 12:15:32.1234567 +05:10')`. The data type of the `date` argument is `datetimeoffset(7)`. The `nanoseconddatepart` return value has a scale of `9 (.123456700)` and the last two positions are always `00`.

> datepart  Return value
>
> year, yyyy, yy    2007
>
> quarter, qq, q    4
>
> month, mm, m  10

I wonder what differences are

- between `year`, `yyyy`, and `yy`?
- between `quarter`, `qq`, and `q`?
- between `month`, `mm`, and `m`?

Thanks.

Comment: No difference, just readability. [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)

Comment: @SqlZim thanks. So is there no  difference in the output format?

Comment: Nope, no difference in output format. `datepart()` always returns an `int`.  [`datename()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql) returns `nvarchar`, sometimes the name of the part, sometimes just a number as `nvarchar`.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, the `datepart()` argument is an English word.  The word is unambiguous and clear, both to the person who writes the code and to anyone else who reads it.

In some cases, the `datepart()` argument is a cryptic collection of one or more letters that bears some relationship to the date part being requested -- however, the relationship is often ambiguous.

Although for a given part, they do the same thing, you can decide which is better to use.